# Making entire column zero if the one element of the Column is equal to zero

Tags: matlab

let's say i have this matrix:

```
 B = [16 0 3 13;5 11 10 0;9 0 6 12;4 14 15 1];

 if(columnContainzero (zeros(thatColumn))
```

is there any function to do so?

Comment: I have no idea how your second matrix is derived from the first. Not only are you zeroing our *rows*, not *columns*, your other rows have changed completely.

Comment: I edited my question thank for pointing it out , I had just put random numbers. @excaza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical indexing:

```
ColumnsContainingZeros = any( B == 0, 1 );
% >> ColumnsContainingZeros = [0 1 0 1]
```

Then make all of the rows in those columns equal to 0

```
B(:, any(B==0,1)) = 0;
% >> B = [ 16     0     3     0
%           5     0    10     0
%           9     0     6     0
%           4     0    15     0 ]
```

To do the same operation on rows instead of columns, use `any(B==0,2)` as your index, and `B(any(B==0,2), :) = 0` to change all columns in those rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing a `sum` operation along the rows, you can use this simple one-liner:

```
B(:,sum(B==0)>0)=0
```

Comment: `any` is more appropriate than `sum` for logical arrays / this operation, likely quicker, and does what it says on the tin... Yields basically [the same one liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545702/3978545).